# Parallax scrolling not working on mobile css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

My parallax scrolling is not working on mobile devices, both android and iOS. The code works great for desktop but not for mobile, be it any browser. Background images are not scrolling in parallax effect. You can check it here https://dkpyk75z6sfdo.cloudfront.net/

Here goes the CSS code,

```
.home {
background: url(assets/images/img1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
display: table;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
#information {
background: url(assets/images/b1.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
display: table;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
#information2 {
background: url(assets/images/ab9.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
display: table;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
#information3 {
background: url(assets/images/c4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
display: table;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML code

```
<!-- first section - Home -->
<div class="home">
<div class="centered">
<h1>PARALLAX WEB DESIGN</h1>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /first section -->    

<!-- second section -->
<div id="information">
<div class="centered">
        <h1>SECTION 1</h1>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /second section -->
```

And so on

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Parallax will never work properly on mobile devices - and here is why.

Mobile browsers are designed to function as efficiently as possible in order to save on battery life. One way that they do that is that they delay JS execution during a scroll event. Symptomatically this will display as the parallax not parallaxing but rather jumping to its new position after scroll completes.

I recommend disabling all parallax once down to mobile viewport.

Further reading on this topic: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/

Comment: Thank you @Korgrue!

Comment: Looks like the link is dead.

Comment: It's 2023. This shouldn't be the case any more.